# When inserting data into the database it is not persistent

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

When I insert or update in my database, I don't get any error and the affected rows are correct, but when I quit the application and re-enter, the database is empty. When checking the size of the database it never changes, it always stays at 4kb.

Any ideas what might happen?

Thanks

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + PasswordEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + PasswordEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + PasswordEntry.TITULO + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + PasswordEntry.DESCRIPCION + " TEXT,"
                + PasswordEntry.CODIGO_ACCESO + " TEXT,"
                + PasswordEntry.PWD_ACCESO + " TEXT ,"
                + PasswordEntry.FECHA_CREACION + " TEXT,"
                + PasswordEntry.FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION + " TEXT"
                + ");");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),e.getMessage());
    }
    // Insertar datos ficticios para prueba inicial
   // mockData(db);
}

 public long savePassword(Password password) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(PasswordEntry.TABLE_NAME,null,password.toContentValues());


}


public class PasswordBD {

public static abstract class PasswordEntry implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME ="CONTRASENYA";

    public static final String TITULO = "titulo";
    public static final String DESCRIPCION = "descripcion";
    public static final String CODIGO_ACCESO = "codigo_acceso";
    public static final String PWD_ACCESO = "pwd_acceso";
    public static final String FECHA_CREACION = "fecha_creacion";
    public static final String FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION = "fecha_ultima_modificacion";
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T3cj.png)

Comment: check at first.. data inserting or not

Comment: If at first it inserts well, I even do select statements and return the data correctly